# Too many arguments for format [-Wformat-extra-args]

Tags: c

```
fprintf(fptr2,"\n\n:%s",ctime(&t),"\t ","\t");
```

this line works fine in dev but not in ubuntu as it generating following error

```
warning: too many arguments for format [-Wformat-extra-args]
 fprintf(fptr2,"\n\n:%s",ctime(&t),"\t ","\t");     
                ^
```

what should i do?

Comment: change to: `fprintf(fptr2,"\n\n:%s\t\t",ctime(&t));`

Comment: "Works fine". Famous last words.

Comment: You have 3 arguments after the format string, but only one `%s` in the format string. What are you expecting it to do with the extra arguments?

Comment: That's a warning, not an error. And the code does the same thing everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

`fprintf` takes a variable number of arguments:

- a `FILE*` output stream
- a format string
- one extra arguments for each `%` format, preceded by an optional width and/or precision if these are specified as `*`.

You should only have one extra argument, a string for the `%s` format.

The extra arguments `"\t"` and `"\t"` are simply ignored, but the compiler gives you a diagnostic as their presence probably indicates some programming error.

Such warnings are a blessing as they prevent many silly bugs, from typos to argument type mismatches.  Your `dev` environment is configured to stay quiet about these, to your disadvantage.  Look into you to fix it: add compiler options such as `-Wall -W` or `-Weverything`.